# Join two tables - One common column with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2000

I have been searching around for how to do this for days - unfortunately I don't have much experience with SQL Queries, so it's been a bit of trial and error.

Basically, I have created two tables - both with one DateTime column and a different column with values in.
The DateTime column has different values in each table.

So...

```html
ACOQ1 (Table 1)
===============

| DateTime | ACOQ1_Pump_Running |
|----------+--------------------|
| 7:14:12  |         1          |
| 8:09:03  |         1          |
```

```html
ACOQ2 (Table 2)
===============

| DateTime | ACOQ2_Pump_Running |
|----------+--------------------|
| 3:54:20  |         1          |
| 7:32:57  |         1          |
```

I want to combine these two tables to look like this:

```html
| DateTime | ACOQ1_Pump_Running | ACOQ2_Pump_Running |
|----------+--------------------+--------------------|
| 3:54:20  |      0 OR NULL     |         1          |
| 7:14:12  |         1          |      0 OR NULL     |
| 7:32:57  |      0 OR NULL     |         1          |
| 8:09:03  |         1          |      0 OR NULL     |
```

I have achieved this by creating a third table that 'UNION's the DateTime column from both tables and then uses that third table's DateTime column for the new table but was wondering if there was a way to skip this step out.
(Eventually I will be adding more and more columns on from different tables and don't really want to be adding yet more processing time by creating a joint DateTime table that may not be necessary).

My working code at the moment:

```html
CREATE TABLE JointDateTime
(
DateTime CHAR(50)
CONSTRAINT [pk_Key3] PRIMARY KEY (DateTime)
);

INSERT INTO JointDateTime (DateTime)
SELECT ACOQ1.DateTime FROM ACOQ1
UNION
SELECT ACOQ2.DateTime FROM ACOQ2

SELECT JointDateTime.DateTime, ACOQ1.ACOQ1_NO_1_PUMP_RUNNING, ACOQ2.ACOQ2_NO_1_PUMP_RUNNING
FROM (SELECT ACOQ1.DateTime FROM ACOQ1
      UNION
      SELECT ACOQ2.DateTime FROM ACOQ2) JointDateTime
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACOQ1
    ON JointDateTime.DateTime = ACOQ1.DateTime
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACOQ2
    ON JointDateTime.DateTime = ACOQ2.DateTime
```

Comment: Don't use `CHAR` to store dates

Comment: What should I use instead? It stores it currently as 11 May 2015 07:14:12 so would probably want it in this format still.

Comment: Use `datetime`, and use `convert` or `format`. which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a plain old `FULL OUTER JOIN` like this.

```
SELECT COALESCE(A1.DateTime,A2.DateTime) DateTime,ACOQ1_Pump_Running, ACOQ2_Pump_Running
FROM ACOQ1 A1 
FULL OUTER JOIN ACOQ2 A2 
    ON A1.DateTime = A2.DateTime
```

This will give you `NULL` for `ACOQ1_Pump_Running`, `ACOQ2_Pump_Running` for rows which do not match the date in the corresponding table. If you need `0` just use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL`.

***Side Note:** : In your script, I can see your are using `DateTime CHAR(50)`. Please use [appropriate types](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)*

Comment: Just tried and worked like a charm. Thanks a lot - seems so simple now but problem is I'm still learning the ropes with SQL so don't always know the best way to go about things!

Comment: Thanks again for a speedy answer - I'm using SQL Server Enterprise Manager Version 8.00.2039 by the way

Comment: Ah, Time for an [upgrade](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2013/04/08/end-of-extended-lifecycle-support-for-sql-server-2000-service-pack-4.aspx)